# Conectarse por ip

Tags: xampp

Quisiera entrar a un proyecto por `ip` desde otra maquina, ambas pertenecen a la misma red, mi pregunta es:

La maquina donde entrare por `ip` al proyecto necesita tener `xampp` instalado o con la otra maquina que esta como servidor funciona?

Comment: por que xampp? estas desarrollando en PHP? en que lenguaje estas desarrollando? solo ejecutarás código del backend o también accederás a una BD?

Comment: En la maquina donde esta el proyecto esta todo, php, apis, base de datos, pero quisiera acceder a la interfaz solamente para hacer registros desde el formulario y demas, como si fuera un usuario final, y xampp, pues solo lo uso como servidor local , pero mi pregunta es esa

Comment: xampp solo es necesario en la pc que contiene el proyecto, deberás configurar una red local para que desde la pc cliente accedas al servicio por medio de la IP que asignes a la PC servidor

Comment: Perfecto! :o Hare unas pruebas...